# Linear Gradient SVG 3 colors increase the width of the middle color

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a linear gradient with the below code

```
<svg width="120" height="240" >
  <linearGradient id="dsp" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
    <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
    <stop class="stop2" offset="50%"/>
    <stop class="stop3" offset="100%"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <style type="text/css">
    .stop1 { stop-color: red; }
    .stop2 { stop-color: yellow; stop-opacity: 0.7; }
    .stop3 { stop-color: green; }
  </style>
```

Now I want to increase the height of the middle color that is the yellow color.
I tried to increase the offset value of yellow color but instead of increasing the width the color band shifts downwards.
I want that the red and green should contain only 10% of the height of the SVG in below format

```
Red >> 15%
yellow >>  70%
green >> 15%
```

This is the color distribution expected.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/egmwqN?editors=1000) ?

Comment: Or this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRvXMM?editors=1000?

Comment: You want a gradient or three stripes? If it is a gradient then you will not get such a split which adds upto 100. There will be portions which will be a color between red and yellow and portions which will be between red yellow and green.

Comment: @harry if you repeat the stop positions you can get a sharp colour transition if you that's what you need.

Comment: @RobertLongson: That's what I am saying by three stripes. The split provided by OP looks like three bars/stripes and not *gradients* (that is, no gradual change). I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @Harry I get it, let's hope the OP does too :-)

Answer (score 1):

just add two more stops in between the start/end stop and the middle...

**EDIT based on squeamish ossifrages comment**

```css
.stop1 { stop-color: red; }
    .stop2 { stop-color: yellow; stop-opacity: 0.7; }
    .stop3 { stop-color: green; }
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="240" >
  <linearGradient id="dsp" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
    <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
    <stop class="stop2" offset="20%"/>
    <stop class="stop2" offset="80%"/>
    <stop class="stop3" offset="100%"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="240" height="120" fill="url(#dsp)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The stop at 50% is unnecessary.